# (ArgumentError) incorrect padding while running mix local.hex

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'm new to Elixir. In a local folder, I'm trying to run `mix local.hex`, but it throws this error:

```
** (ArgumentError) incorrect padding
    (elixir) lib/base.ex:676: Base.do_decode64/2
    (mix) lib/mix/local.ex:91: Mix.Local.find_matching_versions_from_signed_csv!/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/local.hex.ex:30: Mix.Tasks.Local.Hex.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

Here is my mix.exs:

```
defmodule MyPlug.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :my_plug,
      version: "0.0.1",
      elixir: "~> 1.2",
      deps: deps
    ]
  end

  def application do
    [applications: [:cowboy, :plug]]
  end

  defp deps do
    [{:cowboy, "~> 1.0.0"},
     {:plug, "~> 1.0"}]
  end
end
```

**OS**: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
**Erlang version**: Erlang/OTP 18
**Elixir version**: 1.2.3

Appreciate your response on what could be wrong here.

Comment: What's your OS? What's your Erlang version? What's your Elixir version? What's your hex version (`$ mix hex`)?

Comment: @whatyouhide Updated info in question. Trying to install hex locally, so not sure which version you refer. `mix hex` outputs error `** (Mix) The task "hex" could not be found`.

Comment: Did you build Elixir from sources or did you use an apt-get package?

Comment: Built using apt-get: `wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install esl-erlang`, `sudo apt-get install elixir` as given in documentation (http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like)

Comment: I would guess that something went wrong--you should have hex.  The fact that mix is saying ``task "hex" could not be found`` indicates a problem.  I'd discard all of what you've done and start over.

Comment: Check the paths in local.hex.ex - it smells like the download from S3 went wrong. Try to reconstruct the download URL from that source and curl it to see what you get. Archives get installed in ~/.mix, maybe clean out that directory and re-run `mix local.hex`?

Comment: Looks like my proxy was blocking S3 download. After unsetting it, able to do `mix local.hex`.  Thanks all for the comments and pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that may find this question, the answer, which was supplied by the person who asked the question is that in this case his firewall was blocking S3.  When he unblocked S3 he was able to do `mix local.hex`.

Adding the answer and marking it as community wiki.